# Machine Learning Model Alert/Notification system - Python

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

Let's say, I have a Machine Learning model built and does predictions for the future. If I have some predicted values that exceed a threshold, can I set up some type of notification system? It can be in email or a text message. Is it possible to do it in `python`?

I have been searching online, could not find a valid answer. Any thoughts or resources would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this new app: [Hyperdash](https://hyperdash.io).

Comment: @Emre thank you, this looks promising. I'll look into this.